# Can i still improve GPS accuracy?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I'd like to improve GPS location with location manager on my app. I need something really accurate.

- i use Criteria.setAccuray(ACCURACY_FINE) ;
- i average ten location and use it

What can i still do to improve the accuracy ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Averaging locations over a very long time (hours / days / ..) can yield a better result since the factors that decrease accuracy (bad satellite constellations, atmospheric influences, ...) change slowly over time and should cancel out each other at some point. Averaging just 10 fixes might move your location closer towards the inaccurate location that results from those factors but not towards your real location.

Answer (score 0):

The location you get has an accuracy parameter. Take the location with the best accuracy, if multiple locations with the same accuracy you can average them.

Averaging all ten points will actually decrease the overall accuracy (if the points have different accuracy).

Comment: Does averaging work on android? I thought  GPS has a stand still filter such that you dont get new location events when standing still.

Comment: @AlexWien it might even be that way. Anyhow, just averaging location updates will most often not give you a better location, regardless on which updates you get.

Comment: averaging over a period with different satellite constellation should give centimer accuracy. after 24h (86400 fixes) I think they have a centimer accuracy. What do you think?

Comment: Is your answer a guess, or do you have personal experience in averaging GPS positions?

Comment: I have some experience with GPS and mobile apps, however, my answer is mostly based on math/probability. So I can't answer the cm accuracy statement.